# Do you need to use concrete for permanent garden fences?

Tags: fence, footings

I was at the hardware store today, and saw they suggest using concrete for footing the posts. Is this step really necessary as the mycelium in the soil will hold the posts in place, and there won't be a lot of weight on the fence?

I will be pounding the poles directly into the dirt.

It's 6' tall baseball field/skating rink fencing (interwoven) type to hold up vegetables and vines. Minnesota deer probably won't jump a 6' fence.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on what you call permanent**

Increasing entropy is really the only thing that's permanent.

Although you can't say with certainty how long something will last, you do have the ability to influence longevity. Some sticks shoved into the ground are destined for early failure and steel reinforced 12" diameter x 6' 6000 psi concrete will surely be around after the house is torn down. I'm sure your solution lies somewhere in the middle.

***This is decent compromise***
[image]
http://mielcentral.info

I disagree with image regarding treating the underground lumber. I would still treat it.

Your frost line also has to be taken into consideration.

Comment: I'm planning to have the metal poles pounded directly into the dirt.

Comment: Minnesota probably has a 50" frost line. That means you should be going down at least that far. I don't think you'll be able to drive down that far. Fence posts heave, there's no way around it. Going below the frost line helps but it won't eliminate it. Ultimately it's up to you and if you don't mind them shifting around a bit just drive them down as far as you can. You may have to push them back straight every now and then.